# Why MassTransit ConsumeContext injected in constructor doesn't contain Message?

Tags: masstransit

I injected ConsumeContext into MyClass constructor. MyClass is registered as Scoped and injected into MyCommandConsumer constructor. When consumer receives a message in the Consume method ConsumeContext contains Message. But ConsumeContext injected in MyClass constructor (or even in MyCommandConsumer constructor) doesn't. All of the non-public properties return ConsumeContext Not Available exception (or something like this).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the context of consuming a message is scoped to one message. Even though the consumer is instantiated per message if it implements `IConsumer<T>`, only the `Consume` message gets the current message context. That's what the `Consume` method is for.

The `ConsumeContext<T>` is *not* a dependency, it is a context, therefore it *should not* be injected, because dependency injection is, as the name suggests, for injecting dependencies and not for passing parameters. The `ConsumeContext<T>` is a parameter, not a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If your consumer's dependency needs to publish a message, it should put `IPublishEndpoint` on its constructor.

If your consumer's dependency needs to send a message, it should put `ISendEndpointProvider` on its constructor.

As stated in the other answer, depending upon `ConsumeContext` is not recommended.